# How do you update a network option value in the DB via a hook

Tags: multisite, options

I am trying to update the value of an option in the DB for all sites within my multisite, but no success here is the code, been pulling my hair out for the last 2 hours:

```
function simplifyit_upload_folder($blog_id){
      switch_to_blog($blog_id);
      update_option('uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', false);      
      restore_current_blog();
      }
      add_action( 'update_wpmu_options', 'simplifyit_upload_folder' );
```

Thanks to @TheDeadMedic who gave me the answer for filtering but I am looking to update the value in the DB:

```
add_filter( 'option_uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', '__return_false', 100 );
```

Sorry for not being clearer I want to make sure that all blogs in the network are set by default to 0 for YYYYMM upload option but would like to have the possibility to let the Network administrator override it via the WP Network panel should he /she wish to do so for individual sites

Comment: Have you tried `0` instead of `false`?

Comment: Yes I did unfortunately it does not work either!

Comment: The field just ends up with an empty value :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, "update_wpmu_options" is certainly the wrong hook. It doesn't send the blog_id as a parameter, so your code won't ever work with that hook and use of the blog_id parameter.

If you just wanted to update the value on each site, then I would just put `update_option('uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', 0);` on the `init` hook, and wait for each site to be visited once.

Comment: What about wpmu_update_blog_options? There are so many hooks without documentation do you recommend a good site which list them all and their usage, I have been to http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks but still I am a bit of a novice when it comes to WP

Comment: Could be a problem there must be a hook that lets you pass that value straight to the DB without any prior user action! Have updated what I am looking to accomplish above

Comment: Yes, there is such a hook: init, like I stated in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

> The field just ends up with an empty value :-(

If what you want to do is remove the value, as it seems you do from that comment, then you need [`delete_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_option), or [`delete_site_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_site_option). The latter seems most appropriate.

```
function simplifyit_upload_folder(){
    $current_site = get_current_site();
    switch_to_blog($current_site->id);
    delete_site_option('uploads_use_yearmonth_folders');      
    restore_current_blog();
}
add_action( 'update_wpmu_options', 'simplifyit_upload_folder' );
```

I used [`get_current_site`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_current_site) to get the blog ID, as that hook does not pass the value.

I am not completely sure that the hook you want though. It runs in the admin and only when there is `POST` data-- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/network/settings.php#L69

Based on an edit to the question, it sounds like you want the [`wpmu_new_blog`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/ms-functions.php#L980) hook, so that your value is set on blog creation. After which blog admins could alter it, and your code would not interfere.

Untested (I don't have MU on a dev server right now) but...

```
function simplifyit_upload_folder($blog_id){
    // not 100% sure exactly what you need here; caveat emptor :)
    update_option('uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', false);      
}
add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'simplifyit_upload_folder' );
```

Comment: Ok this would not work unless someone updates any settings on the blog in question! The filter above still seems the safest option then!

Comment: That is what it looks like, yes. I haven't done anything to explicitly verify that though.

Comment: As far as the filter being the "safest", I'm not completely sure what you want to accomplish.

Comment: There seems to be tone of other Wpmu option related hooks though none of which I am familiar with another one being wpmu_update_blog_options

Comment: Individual blog admins on multisite don't have the ability to alter the "uploads_use_yearmonth_folders" option at all. That's a per-site setting that is in the network admin area. So I'm thinking there's some other kind of underlying problem here that isn't being clarified properly.

Comment: @otto : well, so much for that. Thanks for the clarification. I didn't realize that.

Comment: Correct @Otto, however when using the one line filter above the Network Admin cannot override the setting on individual sites, which is what we are trying to achieve. ie force the value to 0 instead of 1 by default but still give the network admin the possibility of overriding it to 1 if wanted.

Comment: @TARMAK : Have you tried this? Does it get you half way there, at least?

Comment: Haven't tried this so far sticking with filtering as in my question, although @Otto in theory should work but might not allow for the value to be overridden via the admin panel. Will report back if I implement something else, thanks for the tip !

Comment: TARMAK: You don't leave the code there permanently. You set them all to zero and then take the code out.